# Do we know of any course of action chosen based on historical precedents which was successful?

Tags: political-history

Hegel famously held that we could not learn from history, since the particular circumstances are always too special. The German quote from his „Lectures on the Philosophy of History“ goes as follows:

> Was die Erfahrung aber und die Geschichte lehren, ist dieses, daß Völker und Regierungen niemals etwas aus der Geschichte gelernt [...] haben. Jede Zeit hat so eigentümliche Umstände, ist ein so individueller Zustand, daß in ihm aus ihm selbst entschieden werden muß und allein entschieden werden kann

I tentatively translate:

> But, what experience and history teach us, is this: that peoples  and governments have never learned from history. Each time has such peculiar circumstances, is such a peculiar state of affairs, that therein, decisions can only and have to be made based upon it.

Do we know, perhaps from the memoirs of politicians, of any momentous course of action, chosen based on historical precedents, which was nearly undisputedly successful?

---

For clarification of what I hope for: I don’t care whether the person elected to do or not do something. As far as we have an account of the historical lesson they heeded and of a pretty undisputable good effect. For example, a lot of people saved from famine.

Comment: I am skeptical. Decisions are made on bias and prejudice and justified by appeal to history.  I suspect that in most decision cases, both sides appeal to history to justify their decisions, and one side is proven to be wrong. That said, I'm going to wait to be surprised; the community is smarter than I am.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I see the danger, but I am curious. There could be a nearly indisputable example: „thousands of people saved from famine“...

Comment: I am very afraid I voted to close. Since the OP seems to be doing a semi rant in the name of philosophy ( or philosopher ).

Comment: @Ludi Sweet, I can not see where your focus is about. Sorry for voting (m_m).

Comment: @KentaroTomono Voting the question subjective would be understandable, but I cannot understand the accusation of ranting. All my recent questions stem from my study of European Accounts on China in the 19th and 18th centuries. That made me read small parts of the works of Hegel, Montesquieu, Voltaire and I got questions I didn’t have before.

Comment: @Ludi European Accounts on China and Hegel and others? Are you way heading very different direction? How could have Voltaire known about Qing dynasty when it was at peak only his life period is 1694-1778?

Comment: It seems you are searching for a negative here.  The very nature of the old adage 'those who do not learn from history are doomed to repeat it' implies that decisions based on history are best used to *not* perform the same action again. Actions that did't happen are tough to bring up as examples.

Comment: @justCal Negative? What does the Chinese matters have to do with the past events that human beings never learn from?

Comment: @KentaroTomono comment not directed to you, but to the question.

Comment: @KentaroTomono Voltaire wrote extremely positively on China. For example letter 11 of the „Letters to the English“. You can read the details in a paper titled „Voltaire, sinophile“: https://www.jstor.org/stable/457929?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @justCal an example of electing NOT to do something is just as welcome to me!

Comment: The old adage "*History may not repeat itself; but it sure does rhyme.*" comes to mind. Of course there are variations specific to each age and culture - that doesn't mean there are no lessons to be learned. For example, marching on Moscow (from Western Europe) repeatedly fails - for similar reasons.

Comment: @Ludi Confirmed. But it seems ( my quick research ) Voltair is only glorifying the old Chinese civilization?

Answer (score 2):

The design of the US's Federal government was indisputably based on lessons that the Founding Fathers took from the Roman Republic -- this comes up repeatedly in their writings.  See, for example, [this precis](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED287778).

In general, though, I think it's hard to find cases where the historical precedent can be shown to have been the main driver of a decision. Except by zealots, real decisions are always made for complicated reasons!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that history gets forgotten when it's not in living memory. As such, decisions tend to factor only lessons learned from recent history.

There are examples, mind you. For instance, compare the aftermaths of WW1 and WW2. A few things that happened after WW2, such as the UN, factored in some of the lessons learned from what had failed after WW1, such as the League of Nations.

In passing, Hegel lived through the French Revolution. Surely he'd have remembered that the mistake of being too lenient with France had not been repeated after the Hundred Days. Or for that matter, how the Revolution was in quite a few people's mind after the Restoration. Hegel gave his lectures after it was all over, so presumably he had a longer time scale in mind.

In which case indeed, if you let enough time elapse, collective memory chiefly remembers events that get rehashed on a regular basis (think Holocaust, or Latin classics during the Renaissance). But even then, judging by the re-emergence of fascism and anti-semitism, it's tempting to argue that collective memory isn't remembering much. Part of the reason might have to do with the fact that, in contrast with economists, historians aren't invited when making important decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - they are harder to recognize because it usually seems so natural to *do the right thing* that we can forget the historical precedents. From World War Two alone we see:

- FDR started rearming the U.S. in early 1940 instead of waiting until Dec. 1941 - thus avoiding the very long buildup required by U.S. forces in WW1. He had served in Wilson's administration and seen the problems and challenges well. In consequence the U.S. military was in combat within 10-12 weeks, not months, of Pearly Harbour.
- The lessons of the *armstice* at the end of WW1 were well learned by all the Allies in insisting on a very clearly enunciated "*unconditional surrender*" from both Germany and Japan.
- The U.N., despite it's problems, is much better structured than the League of nations was, learning from the latter's failures in the 1930's.
- The Marshall Plan for rebuilding Europe following WW2 avoided the punitive elements of Versailles - and capitalized on the *unconditional surrender* lesson as well.
- Germany's *blitzkrieg* warfare for avoiding the morass of trench warfare was a brilliant *tactical* lesson - yet at the same time Germany failed to learn any *strategic* lessons. They failed to develop the strategic partnerships and technologies that might have countered U.S. entry. Germany in the 1930's saw only what was already in action in Summer 1918 - u-boats, tanks and aircraft - while completely missing (in the 1930's) all the new possibilities inherent in those technologies: aircraft carriers replacing battleships; jet fighters; long-range fighters; four-engine (long-range) bombers; radar;  and atomic weapons. By contrast while the U.K. and U.S. were slow to see the tactical innovations available they saw most of the strategic ones listed above.

  Note also that the key concepts of *blitzkrieg* - concentration of fire (from tanks and tactical aircraft) is just a repetition of Napoleon's innovative use of artillery 1796-1815. Just as Allied commanders dispersed their tanks amongst infantry formations, diluting their capability and effectiveness, traditional artillery doctrine in 1796 mandated the same for artillery. Napoleon's *grand batteries* changed that by making artillery a key component on offense as well as defense, presaging the massive bombardments of the WW1 Western Front.  This tenet - concentration of fire - would seem to be as old as warfare itself, yet within the past few centuries alone has been ignored, unlearned on a vast scale, across multiple armies and nations, on at least these two obvious occasions.

Further back in history:

- Napoleon's *Battaillon Carre* and Corps du Armee are lessons learned from the problems inherent in the prior method of delegating command based on preassigned *route of march*. Right into June 1815 Wellington's Anglo-Allied Army is employing delegation based on *route of march*, as did the Austrian Army of 1809 - while Blucher's Prussian army, apparently alone of the other Great Powers, has fully adopted a *Corps du Armee* system. The latter's resiliency after Ligny is the result.
- [Gribeauval System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gribeauval_system) of artillery was a lesson learned from the logistical nightmare of supplying adequate shot, shell and cartridge to artillery in the field learned in the War of Austrian Succession and Seven Years War. It also standardized and lightened limbers, carriges and ammunition chests, increasing both mobility and speed on artillery on the battlefield - another *Napoleonic* innovation.
- Observing the hoplite phalanxes of Greece, Philip's development of the sarissa (and the advanced training of a professional phalanx) for Macedonian infantry greatly decreased it's susceptiblity to archery fire while increasing it's melee power against standard phalanxes.
- The steady evolution of the Roman Legion into the cohort system of the Late Republic is a steady succession of learning the lessons of the past (Cannae anyone?). The term [*Marius' Mules*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marian_reforms) epitomizes one such lesson - which enabled Caesar's lightning campaigns in Gaul as well as his siegework at Alesia.

You may note that almost all the items above are strictly military. This is undoubtedly partially selection bias on my interest in history - but not  totally. Battle and combat are brutal arbiters of decision, and vastly more so than a *kriegspiel* referee or a political theorist. Once war is underway those who have failed to learn the lessons of history are, with surprising accuracy and speed, promptly removed from history, most frequently and ideally always on a small scale, out of sight and out of mind.

The transition of one's military from peacetime bureaucracy to wartime brutality is always fraught with danger. Perhaps the most vital lesson to be observed, every time, is to learn the missed lesson on as small a scale as possible, so as to avoid another Cannae or (all lessons to be learned from) Dunkirk:

- Don't chase your enemy into the only available corner that he ***can*** actually escape from.
- Tactical bombing cannot hold ground.
- if your enemy controls the sea - he ***can*** escape. See [John Moore at Corunna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Corunna).
- if control of the airspace is still contested, your enemy's navy can (and will) still operate.
- The English Channel trumps all land armies.

Comment: -1 Lot of mistakes. Rearmament didn't start in 1940, this happened few years before (for all future participants in war) . Unconditional surrender was not absolute  requirement (Japan didn't surrender unconditionally, also Finland, Romania, even Italy etc ...)  Punitive elements (loss of territory, occupation, de-industrialization etc ...) were much harder after WW2 . Germany of course did know about battleships, carriers  and long range bombers before WW2, but didn't have resources to produce such weapons etc ...

Comment: @rs.29: Selective Service Act of 1940 was passed Sept. 1940. Emperor Tojo: "*We have ordered Our Government to communicate to the Governments of the United States, Great Britain, China and the Soviet Union that Our Empire accepts the provisions of their Joint Declaration.*" - that **Joint Declaration** being the Potsdam Declaration demanding unconditional surrender. The demand for unconditional surrender was for the perceived *instigators - Germany and Japan. Eastern Europe got Soviet occupation for 45 years instead. Germany **choosing** to lose the war it started is not an excuse.

Comment: Actually , US Navy started expanding long before that (Vinson-Trammell Act of 1934, Naval Act of 1936 ...) In the same period USAAF also started to grow almost exponentially. As for "unconditional surrender"  it was unconditional surrender of all Japanese armed forces, but there was implicit condition that Japanese kokutai remains in place . In other words, Emperor would not be prosecuted and he will remain formal head of state.

Comment: @rs.29 I concur with you. The Imperial Japanese Army surrendered unconditionally, but Kokutai, which is the emperor, did not "surrender" but kept at safe because the U.S knew otherwise all or nothing war would've continued.

Comment: -1　There are many mistakes too many. What do you mean by Emperor Tojo? Secondly, Tojo was not even a prime minister at Sep 1940, but Konoe Fumimaro link [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fumimaro_Konoe ]. You write as if you know everything, but there are often erroneous information here and there.

Comment: @KentaroTomono: Emperor Hirohito of course. Unfortunately comments can't be edited after five minutes. Brain farts happen from time to time.